# Positive definite matrix and Hormander Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, differential-operators

Let $\varphi \in C_0^\infty$, $\varphi \neq 0$.

We'll consider the inner product in $L^2.$

Let $\alpha ,\beta$ be multi-indices, $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\alpha|,|\beta|\leq m$ and set$$\varphi _{\alpha \beta}=\left \langle \dfrac{D^\alpha}{\alpha !},\dfrac{D^\beta}{\beta !}\right \rangle =\dfrac{1}{\alpha !\beta !}\int D^{\alpha}\varphi \overline{D^\beta \varphi}\,dx.$$Now consider $t=(t_\alpha )$ a "array" of complex numbers, such that $t_\alpha =t_{\alpha '}$, where $\alpha '$ is a permutation of $\alpha$.

Define $u(x)=\sum \limits _{|\alpha |\leq m}t_\alpha D^\alpha \varphi(x)$.

Define the quadratic form in $t$ defined by$$Q(t)=Q((t_\alpha ))=\sum \limits _{i\mid \alpha _i\leq m}\sum \limits _{i\mid \beta \leq m}t_\alpha \overline{t_\beta}\varphi _{\alpha \beta}.$$How to prove that in this conditions, holds$$\sum \limits _{|\alpha |\leq m}\sum \limits _{|\beta |\leq m}t_\alpha \overline{t_\beta}\varphi _{\alpha \beta}=\int \left |\sum \limits _{|\alpha|\leq m}\frac{t_\alpha D_\alpha \varphi}{|\alpha | !}\right |^2\,dx\hspace{2mm}?$$I saw this in Hormander's Thesis, this is **Theorem 2.2** in page 179. He just say that this equality holds, but I can't see that.

I dont need to use that fact, I just want to prove that this quadratic form is positive definite to use coerciveness.

Can anybody help me, please?

P.S: I know that the matrix $(\varphi _{\alpha \beta})$ is hermitian, normal and diagonalizable. But I couldn't prove that the eigenvalues are strictly positive.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing to do with $Q$. The formula holds just by rewriting the sums
\begin{align*}
\sum_{|\alpha|\le m}\sum_{|\beta|\le m}t_\alpha\bar t_\beta\varphi_{\alpha\beta}
&=\sum_{|\alpha|\le m}\sum_{|\beta|\le m}t_\alpha\overline{t_\beta}\frac1{|\alpha|!|\beta|!}
\int D_\alpha\varphi\overline{D_\beta\varphi}dx\\
&=\int\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le m}\frac{t_\alpha}{|\alpha|!}D_\alpha\varphi\right)\overline{\sum_{|\beta|\le m}\frac{{t_\beta}}{|\beta|!}{D_\beta\varphi}}dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: Totally wrong. You don't consider the case in different index. 
If you are correct, then $(a_{1}+a_{2}) \overline{(a_{1}+a_{2})= a_{1}^2+a_2^{2},$ absurdum.

Comment: @Kalashinikov You are talking about $\sum a_\alpha\overline{\sum a_\alpha}\ne \sum (a_\alpha\overline{a_\alpha})=\sum|a_\alpha|^2$. But what I mean is $\sum a_\alpha\overline{\sum a_\alpha}=|\sum a_\alpha|^2$, which contains the mixed terms.